# ¿Como evitar espacios en blanco al guardar el resultado de split en un arreglo con Java?

Tags: java

Estoy trabajando en el desarrollo de una calculadora la cual debe recibir una cadena de caracteres que forman una operación. El propósito es que la calculadora debe hacer los cálculos teniendo en cuenta la prioridad de los operadores. Actualmente la calculadora funciona únicamente si la operación se realiza con operandos de un solo dígito (Ej: 2+9*7), pero en el momento en el que se realiza la operación con operandos de dos dígitos (Ej: 13+9/4), el programa arroja un error. Actualmente estamos utilizando String.split para separar los números de las signos de operación pero nos hemos dado cuenta que al utilizar este, se están creando espacios en blanco en el arreglo de los signos lo cual no permite que la operación se pueda realizar.

este es el código para separar los números de los signos.

```
public static double operacion(String operacion) throws ComandoNoEncontradoException {
        String[] numeros = operacion.split("[*,/,+,-]");
        String[] signos = operacion.split("[0-9]");
```

Comment: Asi que, tu pregunta es ¿como evitar esos espacios en blanco en el arreglo?

Comment: Hola, si, esa es la pregunta.

Comment: Revisando el código cuando se hace el split de signos se crea un arreglo de string de 4 posiciones donde las dos primeras posiciones son un string "" que tampoco es un espacio en blanco

Comment: nos puede informar con cual jdk estas trabajando ¿7 u 8?

Answer (score 1):

Usa TRIM

EJEMPLO:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      String Str = new String("   Welcome to Tutorialspoint.com   ");

      System.out.print("Return Value :" );
      System.out.println(Str.trim() );
   }
}
```

Fuente:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_trim.htm

Comment: Recuerda que en java las variables se escriben con minúscula en camelcase

Answer (score 1):

Una manera diferente con la que puedes intentar que tu programa funcione podría ser utilizando un StringTokenizer. Si estas de separar los números y las operaciones de un string, intenta lo siguiente:

```
public static void operacion(String operacion) throws ComandoNoEncontradoException {
    String[] numeros = operacion.split("[\\+,\\-,\\*,\\/]");
    operadores = new String[numeros.length - 1];
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(operacion, "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9");
    int n = 0;
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        operadores[n] = st.nextToken();
        n++;
    }
```

Ten en cuenta que un StringTokenizer te permite dividir una cadena en tokens y no te crea aquellos espacios en blanco que no permiten que puedas realizar las operaciones en tu calculadora.

Espero esto sea de ayuda.

Comment: No deberías usar las comas en `.split("[\\+,\\-,\\*,\\/]")`. Además, el único símbolo que es necesario escapar es el `-`. Debería ser `.split("[+\\-*/]")`

Answer (score 0):

Les comento que este tema me ha rondado la cabeza todo el día y ya desde hace algún tiempo me lo habia topado y le había hecho el quite, pero hoy que me he puesto a investigar que es lo que pasa. Antes que nada esta investigación se realizo con `JDK 8 (1.8.0_144)` por si acaso.

1. Lo primero que encontre es que cuando al método `String.split` se le pasa como parametro una expresión regular (`regex`) este delega su resolución al método `Pattern.split`.
2. El método `Patter.split` crea un objeto `Matcher` de acuerdo a `regex` y la cadena a la cual se le aplica.
3. Por cada coincidencia que el Matcher encuentre al **inicio de la cadena** crea una subsecuencia de longitud cero (`0`) que adiciona al arreglo del resultado, `String match = cadena.subSequence(indexStart, indexEnd);`, donde `indexStart` es igual a `indexEnd`. La subsecuancia es resuelta por el método `String.substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`.
4. Y es por esto que se crea el string vacio (`""`), pero el método `Pattern.split` no los ignora y los adiciona a arreglo de salida.
5. He tomado el código del método `Pattern.split` y lo he modificado, de forma tal que ignore las cadenas vacias, a este metodo se le realizaron pequeños cambios

**`a)`** Esta como `método estatico` unicamente para poderlo llamar desde el método `main`.
**`b)`** Se adiciono el segundo parametro `String regex` para poder crear el `Matcher`.
**`c)`** Comentariamos el `Matcher` original del método con el fin de crear el propio. `//Matcher m = matcher(input);`
**`d)`** creamos nuestro propio `Matcher`: `Pattern pa = Pattern.compile(regex); m = pa.matcher(input);`y por último adicionamos la validación para no agregar cadenas vacias al resultado

```
if(!match.equals("")){
   matchList.add(match);
}
```

Dejo el metodo modificado y más abajo dejo el método original del `Patter.split()`

```
public static String[] myPatternSplit(CharSequence input, String regex, int limit) {
        int index = 0;
        boolean matchLimited = limit > 0;
        ArrayList<String> matchList = new ArrayList<>();
        //Matcher m = matcher(input); <-- comentariamos esta linea
        Pattern pa = Pattern.compile(regex); // <-- adicionamos un Patter
        Matcher m = pa.matcher(input); // <-- creamos un Matcher
    // Add segments before each match found
    while(m.find()) {
        if (!matchLimited || matchList.size() < limit - 1) {
            if (index == 0 && index == m.start() && m.start() == m.end()) {
                // no empty leading substring included for zero-width match
                // at the beginning of the input char sequence.
                continue;
            }
            String match = input.subSequence(index, m.start()).toString();
            // Adicionamos validación para no ingresar vacios
            if(!match.equals("")){
                matchList.add(match);
            }
            index = m.end();
        } else if (matchList.size() == limit - 1) { // last one
            String match = input.subSequence(index,
                                             input.length()).toString();
            matchList.add(match);
            index = m.end();
        }
    }

    // If no match was found, return this
    if (index == 0)
        return new String[] {input.toString()};

    // Add remaining segment
    if (!matchLimited || matchList.size() < limit)
        matchList.add(input.subSequence(index, input.length()).toString());

    // Construct result
    int resultSize = matchList.size();
    if (limit == 0)
        while (resultSize > 0 && matchList.get(resultSize-1).equals(""))
            resultSize--;
    String[] result = new String[resultSize];
    return matchList.subList(0, resultSize).toArray(result);
}
```

Código original

```
public String[] split(CharSequence input, int limit) {
        int index = 0;
        boolean matchLimited = limit > 0;
        ArrayList<String> matchList = new ArrayList<>();
        Matcher m = matcher(input);

    // Add segments before each match found
    while(m.find()) {
        if (!matchLimited || matchList.size() < limit - 1) {
            if (index == 0 && index == m.start() && m.start() == m.end()) {
                // no empty leading substring included for zero-width match
                // at the beginning of the input char sequence.
                continue;
            }
            String match = input.subSequence(index, m.start()).toString(); <-- Aca genera la cadena vacia
            matchList.add(match); <-- aca la adiciona
            index = m.end();
        } else if (matchList.size() == limit - 1) { // last one
            String match = input.subSequence(index,
                                             input.length()).toString();
            matchList.add(match);
            index = m.end();
        }
    }

    // If no match was found, return this
    if (index == 0)
        return new String[] {input.toString()};

    // Add remaining segment
    if (!matchLimited || matchList.size() < limit)
        matchList.add(input.subSequence(index, input.length()).toString());

    // Construct result
    int resultSize = matchList.size();
    if (limit == 0)
        while (resultSize > 0 && matchList.get(resultSize-1).equals(""))
            resultSize--; <-- aca elimina las cadenas vacias al final del arreglo
    String[] result = new String[resultSize];
    return matchList.subList(0, resultSize).toArray(result);
}
```